# XAMPP with SQL Server in Macbook M1 (Laravel Project)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, xampp, mamp

I am having errors by implementing XAMPP with SQL Server on my Macbook Pro **M1**, I am using docker to install SQL Server and XAMPP to serve my Laravel Projects.

The problem is when I put `extension=sqlsrv.so`and `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so` in `php.ini`once restart the Apache the error messages occur like below:

```
[15-Sep-2021 08:34:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so, 9): Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle
  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so), /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
 
 15-Sep-2021 08:34:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/sqlsrv.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/sqlsrv.so, 9): Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle
  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/sqlsrv.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have also tried to implementing MAMP PRO with SQL Server and surprisingly the error messages are the same as this. I start to thinking, maybe this happens because of M1 Chip, I don't know.

Comment: You'll need pdo_sqlsrv [5.10.0beta1](https://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=pdo_sqlsrv&version=5.10.0beta1) for M1 support. That also requires Microsoft ODBC Driver 17.8 or later.

Comment: unfortunately the error messages still exist, i have installed pdo_sqlsrv and odbc driver 17.8 ,,,